# Error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when running .jar file

Tags: java, terminal, jar, executable-jar

This error occurs when attempting to run my exported .jar file, but I also get the exact same error message when attempting to run the program from within Eclipse. I have no idea what it means or how to go about fixing it.

I have tried Googling the error, but there's always something in the question/answer which takes it out of context, so it's hard to find anything definitive.

Please help!

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class src.lemmini.LemminiFrame
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: LemmCursor/CursorType
```

Comment: Unfortunately not @Tarlog. Since the answers are very much in the context of that particular question, it's difficult to apply it to my own issue. Also, I'm using src that is from an already-working project. All I am attempting to do is compile, run and export it as a .jar to make sure I can do that.

Comment: Those classes `LemminiFrame` and `LemmCursor/CursorType` look proprietary ones. Do you have the source code or the jar of them?

Comment: @MarcoTizzano Yes, I have both the source code and the jar files. Not sure what "proprietary" means (I am a complete beginner)

Comment: Proprietary means that is your own code, not coming from external library you can get from public repository. There must be some dependency issues in your Eclispe project and also in the way you launch the code in the terminal. You need to share more info about your project, it's hard to help  you further at this stage.

Comment: It was indeed down to dependencies. Loading them in via Project>Properties>Java Build Path>Libraries fixed the problem. Thanks, guys :)